# How to create multiple select with filter?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have model with ManyToMany field:

```
class UserSpecialGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name=_('Name')
    )
    users = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=_('Assigned users')
    )
```

This model has hundred thousands of records. And I have form:

```
class UserSpecialGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserSpecialGroup
```

When I create a new object, loading all users take a very long time. Is there a widget improving this?

Comment: Have you considered using a text input box with autocomplete?

Comment: [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to) could be helpful if you do not actually need every single user.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest  [django-autocomplete-light](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).